# Unable to write variables (input) to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently writing a simple text editor in python 3.8, I am unable to write the contents of the user input into a file though. When I open the text file in notepad++ a message pops up saying - "This file has been modified by another program, would you like to reload it?". I've tried writing the input to the file as an array but that does not work.

```
loop = True
    
#Getting file name
filename = input('Filename(Include file extensions) : ')

#Getting What To Write To File
while loop == True:
    text = input('>> ')
    if "EXIT" in text:
        loop = False
        while loop == False:
            #writing to file
            saveFile = open(filename, 'w')
            saveFile.write(text)
            saveFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop structure is a bit off. There is no need for using *"flag"* variables. A more pythonic way is `while True: ... break`. So your code should look more like this:

```py
#Getting file name
filename = input('Filename(Include file extensions) : ')

#Getting What To Write To File
while True:
    text = input('>> ')
    if "EXIT" in text:
        break

#writing to file
with open(filename, 'w') as saveFile:
    saveFile.write(text)
```

Of course this will only write the last input with the `EXIT`, so you might want to make `text` a list or a [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to perform as a buffer, or just dump directly to the file:

```py
#Getting file name
filename = input('Filename(Include file extensions) : ')

#Getting What To Write To File
with open(filename, 'w') as saveFile:
    while True:
        text = input('>> ')
        saveFile.write(text)
        if "EXIT" in text:
            break
```